# How to create a responsive sprite sheet animation in css?

Tags: css, animation, html, sprite, javascript

i've been trying to do this for hours but so far i haven't made any progress.

I have a site with a few animations in it, some will be activated on click and some on hover. something similar to the animation found in this site : http://www.pixelwrapped.com/ the cat tail is reponsive as in when you scale the broswer it scales along with it as well.

this is the code that i am using to create the animation

```
.monster {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            margin: 2% auto;
            background: url('img/le-cloud.png') left center;
            overflow: auto;
            display: block;
            left: 20%;
            top: 40%;

        }
        .monster:hover {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            margin: 2% auto;
            background: url('img/le-cloud.png') left center;
            animation: play .9s steps(18);
            overflow: auto;
            display: block;
            left: 20%;
            top: 40%;

        }
```

i found [this](http://blog.brianjohnsondesign.com/responsive-background-image-sprites-css-tutorial/) tutorial which uses percentages, that works for changing 1 frame not playing the entire 18 frames in this example , i have other animations composed of more than 30 sprites, i looked into [spritely.js](http://spritely.net/) but it wasn't responsive.

Any ideas how can i solve this ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a way better fit for [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: In your example site (pixelwarped.com), as soon as the image starts shrinking, the animated tail is hidden. Meaning that it's not really responsive animation. It would appear that they did it that way, because it would be difficult to scale the small spritesheet image in proportion with the bigger image behind it, all the while keeping the tail in the right position.

Comment: So media queries is the only possible solution i guess, just making 3 different sizes

Comment: Perhaps not the only solution, but the best one that I can think of.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I did consider Gifs as well, do you have any idea about pros,cons or whether it will work at all ?

Comment: @Vincent i did post it in Stackoverflow tho no one answered there, do correct me if I am wrong, it does tap into animations thus i posted it here, as i did ask about the topic before.

Comment: Yeah, the lines are rather blurry, and you're at least bound to get more attention here.

Comment: Check the answer, i found out how !

Comment: Side note: you don't have to reiterate all of your properties in the `:hover` state. You just need to have the ones you *change* from the initial state

Comment: I'm voting this as off-topic because the whole solution is about the use of CSS. Still believe it belongs on StackExchange.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about graphic design within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it eventually! Just in case anyone still cares, Let me do some explaning just so you don't go through what I went throught:

```
    <style>
      div.sprite {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 40%;
/*            Change this to what ever value you desire*/
            height: 0;
            padding-bottom: 40%;
            background-image: url("le-cloud-copy.png");
/*            Add the sprite sheet here, must be on a staright line*/
            background-position: 0 0;
            background-size: 1800%;
/*            I have 18 sprites in the sheet thus it's 1800%, if it was 4 you'd use 400% and so on*/
            display: block;
        }
        div.sprite:hover {
/*            background-position: 500% 0;*/
            animation: play .9s steps(18);
/*            18 steps to go over al the sprites i have, if you had 4 in the sprite the value would be 4 for example */
        }
        @keyframes play {
            100% {
                background-position: 1800% 0;
            }
        }
    </style>
```

And the magic bit is [here](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) include this library and this should work.

```
<script src="js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Including prefixfree for something you can do pretty easily in CSS seems like overkill :P If you are already including it for other things it might be okay, but recommending it for something this short is bad practice

Answer (score 0):

Try using transform's `scale` and whatever break points you need. It's supported in IE9 and above but you can be emulated in IE < 9 using Microsoft's `zoom` property. Others are (not easily) possible using the MS Matrix filter.

```
@media(max-width:1024px){
   .monster {
       transform:scale(0.5);
   }
}
```

Comment: Using `scale` for responsive design is bad practice.

Comment: @Zach Saucier - Interestingly enough you talk about responsive and using scale in your css animation article on CSS Tricks but don't seem to mention it being bad practice. Can you elaborate on that?
"Sadly, percents are not supported by any box-shadow properties so they are not as easily responsive as a native HTML element. However they can still be changed manually in an animation or by using transform:scale(n) on the actual HTML element which they are a part of."

Comment: @Zach Saucier - It'd be nice if srcset was actually supported by more then just web kit. I've use scale and have found no blurriness. Do you have an example? Are you stating that this happens when you resize the browser or from desktop to mobile? If its on browser resize most users (99.9%) do not resize the browser the way we do when testing.

Comment: Upon a bit more thinking: using `scale()` for images is okay as long as 1) The scale value is *less than* 1 (more than 1 is always blurred), 2) the image is positioned absolutely (so that the difference in bounding box and visual appearance doesn't matter), 3) performance doesn't matter much (it would be *best* to load a smaller image if only a smaller image is required), and 4) if it is paired with any other transforms, it needs to be heavily tested because browsers have trouble with certain types of transforms, especially when paired together